# How can I find out which method of a derived class is not implemented?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have an abstract base class, where some functions are implemented and some are purely virtual.

From this base class, I have created a derived class which implements all virtual functions.

However, it still complains that the derived class is abstract. I assume that I have forgotten to implement one method, but I cannot see which one. Is there any way to get a list of inherited virtual methods? I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I have unintendedly defined a new function which is similar to a inherited one, but not the same. Hence, for the compiler, I define a new function instead of implementing the inherited one. The difference was just a "&" because I switched from call-by-value to call-by-reference... The question remains, however.

Comment: In C++11 or later, you can prevent that particular mistake by adding `override` to the declaration of any function that's supposed to be an override. You'll get a friendly error message if it doesn't override anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compilation fails due to an abstract class instantiation attempt you should 
get the exact method that is missing in the output tab, see the following example:

```
8>MVSystemTesting\ReportsServiceMock.cpp(10): error C2259: 'CMailslotIPCChannel' : cannot instantiate abstract class
8>          due to following members:
8>          'void CIPCChannelBase::Listen(void)' : is abstract
8>          d:\tfs\IPCChannelBase.h(27) : see declaration of 'CIPCChannelBase::Listen'
```

Here you can see that `Listen` is not implemented.

This is how you open the output tab:
[image: Output tab]